# React pass props to children on parent hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a navigation menu that is being toggled by a button click event. Once the menu opens I am rendering an hidden NavLinkDetail that will show a little video ONLY when the user hovers the parent element. So when the user hovers the corresponding navigation link, how can I forward the prop to show the video ONLY to that specific child? What's the best approach here?

This is the code for my navigation menu

```
const [navigationOpen, setNavigationOpen] = useState(false);


const toggleNav = () => {
    setNavigationOpen(!navigationOpen);
}


return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <header>
            <div className="container">
                <span><Logo /></span>
                <span><MenuToggler toggleNav={toggleNav} navOpen={navigationOpen} /></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div className={`${styles.navigation}`}>
            <motion.div variants={container} initial="start" animate={navigationOpen ? "end" : ""}>
                <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks} >Sobre Nós
                    {navigationOpen && <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={false}/>}
                </motion.a>
                <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks}>Pet Hotel
                    {navigationOpen && <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={false}/>}
                </motion.a>
                <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks}>Cane Corso
                    {navigationOpen && <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={false}/>}
                </motion.a>
                <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks} >French Bulldog
                    {navigationOpen && <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={false}/>}
                </motion.a>
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

and this is the code for my NavDetail

```
const NavLinkDetail = ({videoSrc, loadVideo}) => {

const [isVideoLoaded, setIsVideoLoaded] = useState(false)

const handleVideo = () => {
    setIsVideoLoaded(true)
}

return(
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <h5 className={styles['navlink-title']}>Nav Link Detail</h5>
        <p className={styles['navlink-text']}>Aliquip sint velit nostrud nulla adipisicing minim irure nisi velit amet sint fugiat quis eiusmod. </p>
        {!isVideoLoaded ? <Spinner /> : null}
        {loadVideo && <video className={`${styles.Video} ${isVideoLoaded ? styles.loaded : ""}`} controls onLoadedData={handleVideo} >
            <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4" ></source>
        </video>}
    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: I think that the most React-ish way to do this is to use the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this way is better:

```
const MotionElement = ({videoSrc,name})=>{
   const [loadVideo,setLoadVideo] = useState(false);
   return (
           <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks} onMouseEnter= 
              {()=>setLoadVideo(true)}  onMouseLeave={()=>setLoadVideo(false)}> 
              {loadVideo && <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={loadVideo} videoSrc={videoSrc} />}
           </motion.a>
          )
}


const [navigationOpen, setNavigationOpen] = useState(false);


const toggleNav = () => {
    setNavigationOpen(!navigationOpen);
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <header>
            <div className="container">
                <span><Logo /></span>
                <span><MenuToggler toggleNav={toggleNav} navOpen={navigationOpen} /></span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div className={`${styles.navigation}`}>
            <motion.div variants={container} initial="start" animate={navigationOpen ? "end" : ""}>
                <MotionElement name="Sobre Nós" videoSrc="corresponding video src" />
                <MotionElement name="Pet Hotel" videoSrc="corresponding video src"  />
                <MotionElement name="Cane Corso" videoSrc="corresponding video src"  />
                <MotionElement name="French Bulldog" videoSrc="corresponding video src"  />

            </motion.div>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Create that MotionElement Component outside of the body of this component or in a separate component file.

Comment: Following your advice I created a new component for the navlink and tweaked my navlink detail a bit and it fixed my issue. I guess I was approaching the problem in a non React-ish way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating a new component for the Navlink

```
const NavLink = ({videoSrc, name}) => {

const [loadVideo, setLoadVideo] = useState(false);

const handleVideo = () => {
    setLoadVideo(true);
}

return (
    <motion.a href="#" variants={navLinks} onMouseEnter={handleVideo}>{name}
       <NavLinkDetail loadVideo={loadVideo} videoSrc={videoSrc} />
    </motion.a>
)
```

}

and then i tweaked my NavLinkDetail a bit

```
const NavLinkDetail = ({videoSrc, loadVideo}) => {

const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState(false)


import(`../../assets/video/${videoSrc}`).then(res => {
    setVideoUrl(res.default)
});


return(
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <h5 className={styles['navlink-title']}>Nav Link Detail</h5>
        <p className={styles['navlink-text']}>Aliquip sint velit nostrud nulla adipisicing minim irure nisi velit amet sint fugiat quis eiusmod. </p>
        {loadVideo && <video className={`${styles.Video}`} controls >
            <source src={videoUrl} type="video/mp4" ></source>
        </video>}
    </div>
)
```

}

Separating concerns fixed my issue